# I am trying to find a way to convert a TimeSpan variable into a integer amount of seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently using a stopwatch in my C# program that is stored as a TimeSpan variable. How could I convert the data stored in that variable to be a rounded number of seconds stored as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=net-5.0) is what you need here:

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional seconds.

You could use this property along with the [`Math.Round` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0) and do something like this (assuming `ts` is your `TimeSpan` variable):

```
int seconds = (int)Math.Round(ts.TotalSeconds);
```

Note that since `Math.Round` returns a `double`, you'll still need to cast the result in order to end up with an `int`.